# Magento Lucene Search

Tags: zend-framework, magento, lucene

Is there a way to configure the ranking of the lucene catalog search in Magento? My main problem is that I want exact-match product names to appear first, so I was wondering if I can boost the ranking of the product name in the search.

Answer (score 0):

Try
http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/Php4u/extension/5999/blast_lucene_seach